# How to filter a column by greater than considering an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

I have a data frame representing the customers ratings of restaurants. `star_rating` is rating of the customer in this data frame.

- **What i want to do is to add a column `nb_fave_rating` in the same data frame that represents the total number of favorable reviews for a restaurant.** I consider a "favorable" opinion if its number of stars is `> = 3`.

```py
data = {'rating_id': ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
        'user_id': ['56', '13','56','99','99','13','12','88','45'],
        'restaurant_id':  ['xxx', 'xxx','yyy','yyy','xxx','zzz','zzz','eee','eee'],
        'star_rating': ['2.3', '3.7','1.2','5.0','1.0','3.2','1.0','2.2','0.2'],
        'rating_year': ['2012','2012','2020','2001','2020','2015','2000','2003','2004'],
        'first_year': ['2012', '2012','2001','2001','2012','2000','2000','2001','2001'],
        'last_year': ['2020', '2020','2020','2020','2020','2015','2015','2020','2020'],
        }


df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['rating_id','user_id','restaurant_id','star_rating','rating_year','first_year','last_year'])
df['star_rating'] = df['star_rating'].astype(float)

positive_reviews = df[df.star_rating >= 3.0 ].groupby('restaurant_id')
positive_reviews.head()
```

From here, i dont know to to count the number of positive reviews for a restaurant and add it to the new column of my initial dataframe `df`.

The output expected would be something like this.

```
data = {'rating_id': ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
        'user_id': ['56', '13','56','99','99','13','12','88','45'],
        'restaurant_id':  ['xxx', 'xxx','yyy','yyy','xxx','zzz','zzz','eee','eee'],
        'star_rating': ['2.3', '3.7','1.2','5.0','1.0','3.2','1.0','2.2','0.2'],
        'rating_year': ['2012','2012','2020','2001','2020','2015','2000','2003','2004'],
        'first_year': ['2012', '2012','2001','2001','2012','2000','2000','2001','2001'],
        'last_year': ['2020', '2020','2020','2020','2020','2015','2015','2020','2020'],
        'nb_fave_rating': ['1', '1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0'],
        }
```

**So i tried this and had a bunch of NaNs**

```py
df['nb_fave_rating']=df[df.star_rating >= 3.0 ].groupby('restaurant_id').agg({'star_rating': 'count'})
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a potential solution with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
#filtering the data with >=3 ratings 
filtered_data = df[df['star_rating'] >= 3]

#creating a dict containing the counts of the all the favorable reviews
d = filtered_data.groupby('restaurant_id')['star_rating'].count().to_dict()

#mapping the dictionary to the restaurant_id to generate 'nb_fave_rating'
df['nb_fave_rating'] = df['restaurant_id'].map(d)

#taking care of `NaN` values 
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

#making the column integer (just to match the requirements)
df['nb_fave_rating'] = df['nb_fave_rating'].astype(int)

print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
  rating_id user_id restaurant_id  star_rating rating_year first_year last_year  nb_fave_rating
0         1      56           xxx          2.3        2012       2012      2020               1
1         2      13           xxx          3.7        2012       2012      2020               1
2         3      56           yyy          1.2        2020       2001      2020               1
3         4      99           yyy          5.0        2001       2001      2020               1
4         5      99           xxx          1.0        2020       2012      2020               1
5         6      13           zzz          3.2        2015       2000      2015               1
6         7      12           zzz          1.0        2000       2000      2015               1
7         8      88           eee          2.2        2003       2001      2020               0
8         9      45           eee          0.2        2004       2001      2020               0
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it in one line.

`groupby()`, `transform` boolean selection and convert outcome into an `integer`.

```
  df['nb_fave_rating']=df.groupby('restaurant_id')['star_rating'].transform(lambda x: int((x>=3).sum()))

 rating_id user_id restaurant_id  star_rating rating_year first_year  \
0         1      56           xxx          2.3        2012       2012   
1         2      13           xxx          3.7        2012       2012   
2         3      56           yyy          1.2        2020       2001   
3         4      99           yyy          5.0        2001       2001   
4         5      99           xxx          1.0        2020       2012   
5         6      13           zzz          3.2        2015       2000   
6         7      12           zzz          1.0        2000       2000   
7         8      88           eee          2.2        2003       2001   
8         9      45           eee          0.2        2004       2001   

  last_year  nb_fave_rating  
0      2020             1.0  
1      2020             1.0  
2      2020             1.0  
3      2020             1.0  
4      2020             1.0  
5      2015             1.0  
6      2015             1.0  
7      2020             0.0  
8      2020             0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

- The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071764) from [Grayrigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5604562/grayrigel), using `map`, is the fastest solution.
- Use `.groupby` to get the count of ratings `>=3` for each `restaurant_id`
- `.merge` `positive_reviews` back to `df`.

```py
positive_reviews = df[df.star_rating >= 3.0 ].groupby('restaurant_id', as_index=False).agg({'star_rating': 'count'}).rename(columns={'star_rating': 'nb_fave_rating'})

# join back to df
df = df.merge(positive_reviews, how='left', on='restaurant_id').fillna(0)

# display(df)
  rating_id user_id restaurant_id  star_rating rating_year first_year last_year  nb_fave_rating
0         1      56           xxx          2.3        2012       2012      2020             1.0
1         2      13           xxx          3.7        2012       2012      2020             1.0
2         3      56           yyy          1.2        2020       2001      2020             1.0
3         4      99           yyy          5.0        2001       2001      2020             1.0
4         5      99           xxx          1.0        2020       2012      2020             1.0
5         6      13           zzz          3.2        2015       2000      2015             1.0
6         7      12           zzz          1.0        2000       2000      2015             1.0
7         8      88           eee          2.2        2003       2001      2020             0.0
8         9      45           eee          0.2        2004       2001      2020             0.0
```

### `%timeit` comparison

- Given the 9 row dataframe, `df` in the question

```py
# create a test dataframe of 1,125,000 rows
dfl = pd.concat([df] * 125000).reset_index(drop=True)

# test with transform
def add_rating_transform(df):
    return df.groupby('restaurant_id')['star_rating'].transform(lambda x: int((x>=3).sum()))


%timeit add_rating_transform(dfl)
[out]:
222 ms ± 9.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# test with map
def add_rating_map(df):
    filtered_data = df[df['star_rating'] >= 3]
    d = filtered_data.groupby('restaurant_id')['star_rating'].count().to_dict()
    return df['restaurant_id'].map(d).fillna(0).astype(int)


%timeit add_rating_map(dfl)
[out]:
105 ms ± 1.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# test with merge
def add_rating_merge(df):
    positive_reviews = df[df.star_rating >= 3.0 ].groupby('restaurant_id', as_index=False).agg({'star_rating': 'count'}).rename(columns={'star_rating': 'nb_fave_rating'})
    return df.merge(positive_reviews, how='left', on='restaurant_id').fillna(0) 


%timeit add_rating_merge(dfl)
[out]:
639 ms ± 26.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Great Analysis @Trenton. Thanks for sharing. There is always so much to learn from your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Counting the cases where the rating is >= 3.0

```
df['nb_fave_rating'] = df.groupby('restaurant_id')['star_rating'].transform(lambda x: x.ge(3.0).sum()).astype(np.int)
```